# OS X: Is there a way to block all incoming / outgoing connections EXCEPT for localhost?

Tags: macos, internet

Wondering if there's a way for me to block the internet except for localhost while I'm developing on a local machine.

Comment: Why not pull out the cable / disconnect from WiFi? `localhost` resolves to a local loopback interface and does not require any network connectivity.

Comment: Disconnecting wifi gives me some unexpected behaviors in my dev environment: some assets won't load correctly, etc.

Comment: Those problems will likely persist if you block all incoming and outgoing traffic. I highly recommend solving the actual problem (i.e. assets not loading, even though they should come from localhost). Could it be that those assets are loaded externally?

Comment: in that case, is it possible to selectively whitelist some assets on a per-needed basis and otherwise block all other traffic?

Comment: @VSC_question sure, but now this is getting into how to set up a firewall instead of a security question

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks

> Wondering if there's a way for me to block the internet except for localhost while I'm developing on a local machine.

Macos does that by default. Only incoming connections allowed are those used by services installed (You can verify this statement by going to system preferences -> firewall and reading).

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251144858
https://support.apple.com/en-sa/guide/mac-help/mh11783/mac

Anytime connections need to be restricted, firewall is the main component to configure, but not the only one